# Registration Page- PHP Error

Tags: php, mysql, registration

I have created a registration page using PHP. The control always goes into else part('Error'). I have defined the database, used the same id used in the form fields but still its the same. I'm unable to figure this out. I'd really appreciate any help.

Here's my code :

```
<?php
require_once 'connectdb.php';

$dbc = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user , $mysql_pass , $mysql_db ) or die('Error Connecting to database');
if ( isset($_POST['submit'] ) )
{

$first_name =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['first_name']));
$last_name =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['last_name']));
$password1 =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password1']));
$password2 =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password2']));
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['email']));

if (!empty($first_name) &&  !empty($last_name) && !empty($password1) && !empty($password2) && ($password1==$password2) )
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE email='$email'";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) 
    {
        $password2 = md5($password1);
        $query = "INSERT INTO user_db(fname, lname, email, password) VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password2')";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error Querying database-Adding info');
        echo '<strong>Registration Successful</strong>';

        mysqli_close($dbc);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'An account already exists for with this email id. Kindly use a different one<br /> ';
        $email = "";
    }
}

else
{
    echo 'Please enter all the fields correctly, including the desired password correctly <br/>';
}

}
 // The control goes everytime into this else part
 else
{
    echo 'Error';
}

mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

Comment: what does var_dump( $_POST['submit] ); say?

Comment: does your submit button have name='submit' ??

Comment: what is the name of your submit button is it really submit? and has your form actio method="post" ?

Comment: +1 for using a modern MySQL library, for escaping your data, and for posting code. As a minor security point, consider silently accepting registrations for users who are already registered, otherwise users can determine whether person X is registered - a privacy issue. You can email that person and say 'you are already registered, password unchanged' rather than the usual registration email, if you like.

Comment: Thanks. You brought out an important privacy issue. Will consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['submit']` is not set. This is why your code goes into the "error"-part.

You must set names of the html-elements so PHP knows what to look for.

Something like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" > 
First Name :    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" /><br/> 
Last Name : <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" /><br/> 
Email    : <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br/> 
Password : <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1" /><br/> 
Repeat Password:<input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" /><br/> 
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> </form>
```

Also consider not to mix types of html-elements and id/names of those. submit is not the ultimate name for an html-element because it could bring a lot of confusion. Instead name the submit-button to something like:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit-registration" value="submit" name="submit-registration" /> </form>
```

Comment: I have used isset($_POST['first_name'] && ...)
also. But it didn't work too.

Comment: You have to set name-attributes to your html-elements. (Not just id)

Comment: How does the id and name differ?

Comment: To make a long story short... ID is unique. Name doesn't have to be. I would say this a question about validating your html. If you set two elements with the same ID, the html will not validate correctly. It's also a question about how to access different elements. You access ID's through jQuery (for examples) by using $('#submit-registration').... (Id has to be defined in that case)

Answer (score 0):

Show the HTML please. 
My guess would be that you don't have an `<input>` tag with `name="submit"` and a `value="something"` in your form :-)

Comment: <form action="index.php" method="POST" >
 First Name : <input type="text" id="first_name" /><br/>
 Last Name  : <input type="text" id="last_name" /><br/>
 Email    :    <input type="text" id="email" /><br/>
 Password   : <input type="password" id="password1" /><br/>
 Repeat Password:<input type="password" id="password2" /><br/>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>

Comment: You have to set names of the elements, not just ID's.

Comment: your php is looking for name attribute

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I changed the id="" into name ="" in the form. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

That tells you one thing.. `submit` is not passed in your forum. Heres a simple test. In your form add an input like so `<input type="text" name="submit" />` and then try again